# Custom JavaScript is not allowed in amp

Tags: amp-html

Am getting Custom JavaScript is not allowed [image]

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Custom Javascript not allowed in AMP, you can use [amp-bind](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-bind)

A simple example:

```
<p [text]="'Hello ' + foo">Hello World</p>

<button on="tap:AMP.setState({foo: 'amp-bind'})">Say "Hello amp-bind"</button>
```

Don't forget add Required Script in header:

```
<script async custom-element="amp-bind" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-bind-0.1.js"></script>
```

Comment: Latest documentation states, that custom JavaScript is allowed. Up to 150kb uncompressed is possible to add to your amp page

Comment: But I could not find any validator or browser that implements the latest version of amp

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same issue on [this AMP page](https://www.stagbite.com/sushant-singh-rajput-bookshelf/), and after getting through all the answers, blogs, and videos, my solution came to be is disabling comments in AMP posts.

Answer (score 0):

AMP supports custom JS now. You can use `amp-script` and make it point to the script. But for performance issue you have to add `type="text/plain"`. Look at the following example with `amp-list`.

```
<amp-script layout="fixed-height" height="100" id="dataFunctions" script="fetch-data-script"> </amp-script>

<script id="fetch-data-script" type="text/plain" target="amp-script">
   function fetchData() {
      const data = {
        // follow this format for amp-list
        items: [
            { id: 1, name: "Tom" },
            { id: 2, name: "Jerry" },
        ],
      };
      return data;
    }

exportFunction("fetchData", fetchData);

</script>

<amp-list id="amp-list" width="auto" height="100" layout="fixed-height" src="amp-script:dataFunctions.fetchData" template="myTemplate">
    <div placeholder>Loading ...</div>
    <div fallback>Failed to load data.</div>

    <template type="amp-mustache" id="myTemplate">
        <div>
            <h4>
                {{id}}. {{name}}
            </h4>
        </div>
    </template>
</amp-list>
```

I want to point out few details here.

1. `script` attribute of your `amp-script` should match `id` attribute of your script tag.
2. `id` attribute of your `amp-script` should be mentioned in the src attribute of the `amp-script` along with the function name.